# date do bootstrap não apresenta no form, OffsetDateTime criado no back-end, para atualizar a data?

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, spring

Então crio o OffsetDateTime no back com Java spring, na hora de atualizar a data no front, com angular e bootstrap, não apresenta a data para ser atualizada ?

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">   
  <label for="dataCriacao" style="margin-left: 90px;">DATA CRIAÇÃO</label>
                        <input type="date" id="dataCriacao" formControlName="dataCriacao" placeholder="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm" 
                           required  style="background-color: lightblue; margin-left: 90px;"/>
                    </div>   
                      <br>      
                      <div class="col-sm-3">   
                        <label for="dataAlteracao" style="margin-left: 2px;">DATA ALTERARAÇÃO</label>
                        <input type="date" id="dataAlteracao" formControlName="dataAlteracao" placeholder="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm" 
                           required  style="background-color: lightblue; margin-left: 8px;"/>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Então, a solução foi usar o datetime

```
<div class="col-sm-3">   
                        <label for="dataAlteracao" style="margin-left: 2px;">DATA ALTERARAÇÃO</label>
                        <input type="datetime" id="dataAlteracao" formControlName="dataAlteracao" placeholder="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm" 
                           required  style="background-color: lightblue; margin-left: 8px;"/>
                    </div>
```